# How can I access an unordered list item from its value?

Tags: javascript, html

I have an unordered list with values a, b, c, d and so on. How can I select the "li" element which has a value a?

Comment: `<ul>`/`<li>` does not have a `value`. Do you perhaps mean based on `textContent`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Document.querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to get all the `li` tags and then use [Array.prototype.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to get the desired element. We are using the spread operator here to convert the NodeList returned by querySelectorAll to a normal array

```js
const liElements = [...document.querySelectorAll("li")];
const required = liElements.find(element => element.innerText === "a"); // li tag having content a
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the value of a  element, you would want to give It a specific ID

```
<ul>
 <li id="a">a</li>
 <li id="b">b</li>
 <li id="c">c</li>
</ul>
```

For the Javascript, you would want to store It in a variable :

```
let listElement = document.getElementbyID("a");
```

Answer (score 0):

you can select the parent element and then convert the the children into an array and loop though it

```html
<ul id="list">
<li>a</li>
<li>b</li>
<li>c</li>
<li>d</li>
<li>e</li>
</ul>
</div>
<script>

child=document.getElementById("list").children
Array.from(child).forEach(el=>{
  if(el.textContent=="a")
  console.log(el)
})
</script>
```